# Find input value in other input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check and find if a value of the current input field is found in other input fields on the page.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input.card-label", function(){

    var ths = $(this),
    par = ths.closest(".inputContainer"),
    val = ths.val();

    if (ths.closest(".allInput").find("input.card-label").val() != val) {
        par.removeClass("dupe");
    } else {
        par.addClass("dupe");
        fle.prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

I seem to have a partial success. When I edit a value that's a duplicate, the "dupe" class is removed, but when I intentionally enter a duplicate value, the "dupe" class is not added. What am I missing?

Comment: it would really help to see the accompanying HTML so we can understand the structure and what elements these various CSS classes relate to

Comment: A hint: if you have many inputs, and the number may vary, you need to iterate over all of them; in the piece of code you provided, iteration is missing. Think about how to select all input elements except the target input, map them to values, and then iterate over these values, checking each of them against the one of the target input.

Comment: Shouldn't jQuery selector find a first match? I just need to know if there's a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a class added when the value of an input is the same as the value of another input. The following code adds the keyup event to any input, then loops over all other inputs to determine if the current input's value is a duplicate, in which case it adds a CSS class.

I have gone for simplicity and just used the `input` selector. You should be able to tailor this to your needs.

```js
$(function () {
  $('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
    // reference to this input
    var input = $(e.currentTarget)
    // get all inputs which are not this input
    var allInputs = $('input').not(this) 
    
    // loop through all other inputs
    for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; ++i) {
      // if another input's value is the same as this, add the class
      if ($(allInputs[i]).val() == input.val()) {
        input.addClass('dup')
      } else { // otherwise remove it (if it exists)
        input.removeClass('dup')
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.dup {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```